# how to create Drop Down dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

i'm trying to populate dropdown when there is some changes in root drop down but its not working .
**code :**

```
$('#book_selection').change(function(){
    alert("changed");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = 'df';
    option.value = 'df';
    var temp = document.createElement('select');
    temp.appendChild(option);
    var root = document.getElementById('book_selection');
    root.appendChild(temp);
    alert("done");
});
```

Comment: If you have jQuery loaded, why aren't you taking advantage of it?

Comment: You can't have a menu as a child of another menu. What are you trying to do?

Comment: actually i just want to add another drop down right below it. @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after, adding a new select menu if the first one is changed:

```
$('#book_selection').change(function() {
    $("<select />").append($("<option>", {"value": "me", "text": "me"})).insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Of course you would need to add your own logic or provide an array as to what you wanted the new options to be.

http://jsfiddle.net/6EzZs/

Comment: how to set its ID and then how to get it ?

Comment: Change the first bit to (the same syntax as the option):
$("<select />", {"id": "myID"}).
Selecting it would be normal jQuery syntax:
$("select#myID")

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$('#book_selection').change(function(){
            $(this).next('<select><option>option1</option><option>option2</option></select>')
        });
```

Comment: error on browser console :
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: >

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#book_selection').change(function(){
    var newSelect=document.createElement('select');
    var selectHTML="";
    for(i=0; i<choices.length; i=i+1){
        selectHTML+= "<option value='"+choices[i]+"'>"+choices[i]+"</option>";
    }

    newSelect.innerHTML= selectHTML;
    document.getElementById('book_selection').appendChild(newSelect);
});
```

check this - http://jsfiddle.net/7Gwbw/

Answer (score 0):

Its simple !!

```
$('#book_selection').change(function(){
     alert("changed");
     $('#book_selection').append(new Option("text","val"))
     alert("done !!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add items when changing the dropdown should at least have a previous element.

If you want to fill it up when you click on it here is the code:

```
 $('#book_selection').click(function(){
       alert("changed");
       $('#book_selection').append('<option value="df">df</option>');
       alert("done");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#book_selection").change(function () {
        $(this).after($("<select>").append($("<option>", {
            value: 'df',
            text: 'df'
        })));
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/J34hN/4/)